# Home automation system by speech recognition

Tags: speech-recognition, home-automation

I am pursuing B.Tech in Computer Science. This is my final year project and I have finished a part of it. I have used Java and the application can understand the speech as it can convert the speech to text but now I am confuse what to do next. Please help me out.

Comment: Please, try to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/about. Namely do not ask about: **Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)**

Comment: Home automation - "application can understand the speech as it can convert the speech to text" - "I am confuse what to do next" - well if you got the speech to text then I suppose its about link 'actions'to certain words, or phrases :)

Answer (score 0):

home automation - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X10_(industry_standard)

speech recognition - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition

some interesting reading :

http://www.voicepod.com/#3

http://james.lipsit.com/home.htm

http://hacknmod.com/hack/diy-voice-activated-home-automation/

http://www.embeddedautomation.com/forum/showthread.php?t=2149

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgCMHIHReLQ

---

heres some Ruby repos:

https://github.com/hiddentao/google-tts

https://github.com/c2h2/tts

https://github.com/taf2/speech2text

https://github.com/ryanfb/ruby-opencv